# TLS handshake errors in Kubernetes API server logs

Tags: kubernetes

I'm working on a [terraform configuration for a Kubernetes cluster in AWS](https://github.com/ericandrewlewis/kubernetes-via-terraform).

I've got the cluster running. I can speak to it from my local machine via kubectl and start pods.

I noticed kubectl taking 10s to respond after 12 hours of launching the cluster, so looked around for possible causes.

I notice a lot of TLS handshake errors in the apiserver's container log that look like this

```
I0223 13:50:31.126486       1 logs.go:40] http: TLS handshake error from 10.0.3.5:49360: remote error: bad certificate
I0223 13:50:31.168158       1 logs.go:40] http: TLS handshake error from 10.0.4.5:39214: remote error: bad certificate
```

`10.0.3.5` and `10.0.4.5` are the Kubernetes worker/minion instances which I provisioned with [appropriate TLS assets](https://github.com/ericandrewlewis/kubernetes-via-terraform/blob/master/user-data/worker.yml#L20-L30). Kubelet on the workers must be communicating with the apiserver — I see the nodes if I run `kubectl get nodes` on my computer, and I can launch pods via `kubectl` as well, which the workers would read from the API.

Any thoughts on what these errors could mean?

Comment: What is in your worker-kubeconfig.yaml file? Does it specify a bearer token or client certificate for auth? Does is use the insecure connection or specify the cluster CA to validate the certificate presented by your apiserver? The `--tls-cert-file` and `--tls-private-key-file` arguments are used by the HTTPS server built into the kubelet and don't affect any kubelet->master connectivity.

Comment: any news on this problem?

Comment: If you were able to resolve the issue, please consider posting a self-answer so the community can benefit.

Comment: I too have the same issue. Did you find the answer?

Comment: I am having same issue please post the answer