# TLS handshake error while communicating with kubeapi

Tags: python, kubernetes, keycloak

I am using python Kubernetes client to fetch kubernetes resources by providing token.

I am getting the following error:

> http: TLS handshake error from < IP >: < PORT >: remote error: tls:
>   bad certificate

IP mentioned above belongs to my worker node.

I have already gone through the following links:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/70411
[TLS handshake errors in Kubernetes API server logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579584/tls-handshake-errors-in-kubernetes-api-server-logs)

Comment: Hi,  how is the k8s client authenticating with api-server?  how are you getting the token ?

Comment: I am getting token from my angular application by calling keycloak REST API and passing it to my backend

Comment: Is your client running as a pod inside the cluster ?

Comment: yes, my python file(client) is inside one container inside that cluster

Comment: I think then  you need to use the token from /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount locations 

`curl -v --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" https://kubernetes.default/
`

Comment: how does this token gets generated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193031/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-rajat-badjatya).